# I have lunch at 1 pm

Tags: tenses, present-tense, perfect-aspect

can anyone please explain me is it correct to say "I have lunch at 1 pm". My doubt is if it is correct then how can we use a specific time expression with present perfect tense? If it is wrong to say "I have completed my homework yesterday." which implies specific time expression with present perfect tense. I have doubt in using time expressions with present perfect tense. i will be thankful if any one gives me relevant info.

Comment: I think you may be directed to English Language Learners but the present tense is used for habitual actions, so *I have lunch at 1 pm* is perfectly correct but it means *usually* or *every day*. *I have completed my homework yesterday* is incorrect but this is a different tense - the tense of your first sentence is present, not present perfect.

Comment: so "I have eaten lunch at 1 pm". is a correct statement in present perfect tense?

Comment: "I have eaten lunch at 1 pm" is correct?

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question - it is grammatical but it does not mean *I had lunch at 1pm*.

Comment: So I have eaten lunch at 1 pm. is grammatically correct

Comment: My only doubt is "at 1 pm" is specific time and can we tag this time frame with present perfect tense or not? if yes please explain. There is a lot of difference in "I have lunch at 1 pm" and "i have eaten lunch at 1 pm" the first one is simple present and second one is Present perfect tense. and my English teacher asked me not use specific time frames with present perfect tense.

Comment: Yes we can, but it doesn't give you the meaning I think you want. If you put *I am having lunch at 1 pm* in the past, it has to be *I had lunch at 1 pm*. I think you are misusing these tenses and should start with something simpler. Your teacher will just be trying to introduce things in a logical order.

Comment: These two constructions are very different. The first uses the verb *have* in a fairly plain meaning. There are two usages this phrasing would work for (1) *to have lunch* (works for any meal or meal-like sitting), meaning to eat the midday meal; since you use it in the present tense, the meaning would be habitual--you have lunch daily at 1pm or (2) the use of *have* for schedules, "I have yoga class at 3:00pm". This would be about an upcoming event--you *have* it now in that it is scheduled now.

Comment: On the other hand, in "I have completed my homework", *have* is used as an auxiliary verb, to change the tense. To use the same tense for the lunch example, you would say "I have had lunch." As a matter of usage, it happens that "I have had lunch at 1:00" would not imply you did it today, but imply you did it ever. The simple past tense works better ("I had lunch at 1:00") just as it works best for the homework example ("I completed my homework yesterday").

Comment: again you confused me. "I have had lunch " is perfectly ok. But "I have had lunch at 1 pm" is incorrect as per me as it is referring specific time in past. I require only a clarification regarding usage of "specific time expression" in present perfect tense as it s not permitted to use such exact time expressions( 1pm,8 am, 6 pm, 5 am) in present perfect tense.

Comment: [“I had finished the work on friday” / “I have finished the work”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26256) and [I didn't phone Peter this morning / I haven't phoned Peter this morning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303644)

Comment: What are you trying to say?  And in what context?

Comment: There is no context. I was asked in competitive examination to find out error in sentence "I have eaten lunch at 1 pm" and i marked "at 1 pm" as error as specific time frame has been tagged to a sentence in present perfect tense "I have eaten lunch". Have I identified it correctly or I am wrong? If wrong please clarify me. I will be thankful to you

Comment: There is no error in that sentence but I think the person who has set the exam is thinking of it as an incorrect version of *I ate lunch at 1 pm*, so I suspect your answer will be marked as correct. You don't seem to have taken on board that it is not grammatically incorrect but does not mean the same as *I ate lunch at 1 pm*, so it would be wrong IF you used it to mean *I ate lunch at 1 pm*. That is the situation the person who set the exam must have had in mind.

Comment: You don't have doubts; you have questions. You're copying the usage of doubt from some other language into English in a way that does not apply. You also cannot use *explain* the way you have: the predicate frame requires that things be explained to you,  not that they be explained you, which is ungrammatical. Please visit our sister site for [ell.se].

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

> Over the past ten years, I've eaten lunch at 1 pm.

Or even:

> Recently, I've been eating lunch at 1 pm.

If it's just about a single past action and you have a *finished time* phrase, use the past simple:

> I had lunch at 1 pm.

If it's habitual, present simple would do:

> I have lunch at 1 pm.

And no, we CAN'T use the present perfect with a finished time word:

Wrong: I've seen him yesterday.

Comment: So finally the statement "I have eaten lunch at 1 pm" is wrong?

Comment: It can be correct if you look at my first example. The time phrase could be implied.

Comment: There is no context. I was asked in competitive examination to find out error in sentence "I have eaten lunch at 1 pm" and i marked "at 1 pm" as error as specific time frame has been tagged to a sentence in present perfect tense "I have eaten lunch". Have I identified it correctly or I am wrong? If wrong please clarify me. I will be thankful to you

Comment: @RAVIVARMA *I have eaten lunch at 1 p.m.* makes sense as a general description of an event that could have taken place once or several times in the past. It's not an error. *I have seen him yesterday* has the same grammatical form, but while it's arguably *syntactically* correct, it's *semantically* incorrect simply because we don't use that specific type of phrase. We might say *I am always seeing him the day before I exercise* (making use of a habitual previous-day reference), but the specific phrasing of *I have seen him yesterday* is simply (and perhaps arbitrarily) not used.

Comment: @ravivarma in that case, yes. You could have identified the mistake in two ways, pointing to the time phrase or the tense. You went with the former.

Comment: Sorry to say that I could'nt still appreciate your clarification. As a rule in present perfect I followed specific time frame are not to be included (I still think "1 pm" as specific time in past) so I taught better to use simple past "I ate lunch at 1 pm".